# How to concatenate BERT-like sentence representation and word embeddings - Keras & huggingface

Tags: keras, nlp, pytorch, word-embedding, huggingface-transformers

How to concatenate BERT-like sentence representation and word embeddings - Keras & huggingface

I am following this Keras tutorial to combine Hugging Face transformers with other layers:
https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_extraction_with_bert/

I want to concatenate the transformer embedding layer (included in the tutorial) with some regular word embeddings:

```
encoder = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

input_ids = layers.Input(shape=(max_transformer_len,), dtype=tf.int32)
token_type_ids = layers.Input(shape=(max_transformer_len,), dtype=tf.int32)
attention_mask = layers.Input(shape=(max_transformer_len,), dtype=tf.int32)
embedding1 = encoder(
    input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)[0]`

input_wordembedding = Input(shape=(max_sentence_len,), dtype='int32', 
                 name='we_input')
embedding2 = Embedding(output_dim=wordembedding_VECTOR_SIZE, 
                 input_dim=wordembedding_VOCAB_SIZE,
                 input_length=max_sentence_len,
                 weights = [emb_matrix],
                 name='emb1')(we_input)

z = Concatenate(name='merged')([embedding1, embedding2])
```

My problem is that the layer `embedding1` has sub-words representations and `embedding2` has words representations. Then, I want to do a max-pooling of the sub-words in the `embedding1` layer. In this way, I will obtain word representations with a transformer model.

Does anyone know how to approach this problem in Keras? If it is impossible to solve it with Keras, is it doable in PyTorch? How?

Comment: Have you made any progress?